# How to get resource name for a task using microsoft flow - project online connector

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, ms-project, power-automate

I'm using a project online web app in sharepoint. And I'm trying to use flow connectors - project online connector to send an email notification to resource name when a new task is created in project online.

But I'm unable to find resource name for each task which has been created and assigned a resource.

I have tried using create new task trigger but task name and resource name is not listed together in dynamic content of this trigger due to which I'm unable to identify which task is being assigned which resource.

I have tried using create new resource trigger but this executes only when a new resource is created and not when a new resource is assigned to a task. So my flow is running non stop.

Trigger- When a new task is created
Root site URL - https:/nameofwebsite.sharepoint.com/nameofprojectonlineapp

Action- Send an email notification (V3) (Preview)

To- ResourceName/ResourceEmailID "This option is not available unless i use resource trigger"
Subject- Returned tasks Project name
Email Body- You have to finish this task within "Returned tasks Task start date" and "Returned tasks Task finish date"

I want to find resource name for each task using connector in microsoft flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I extract the Resource Name...

First you List Tasks

Then you Apply to Each with the Output "Returned tasks"

[image]

Then within the Apply to Each

- you Send an HTTP request to SharePoint (I stored ProjectID as a variable)

[image]

- Now you Parse JSON using the body from HTTP request as the Content

[image]

Here is the Schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "d": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "results": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "__metadata": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "uri": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "CustomFields": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "uri": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Owner": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "uri": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Parent": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "uri": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Resource": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "uri": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Task": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "__deferred": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "uri": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "ActualCostWorkPerformed": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "ActualOvertimeCost": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "BaselineCost": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "BaselineCostPerUse": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "BaselineFinish": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "BaselineStart": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "BaselineWork": {},
                            "BaselineWorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "BaselineWorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "BudgetedCostWorkPerformed": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "BudgetedCostWorkScheduled": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "CostVariance": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "CostVarianceAtCompletion": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "Created": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "CurrentCostVariance": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "Finish": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "FinishVariance": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "FinishVarianceMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "FinishVarianceTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "IsConfirmed": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "IsOverAllocated": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "IsPublished": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "IsResponsePending": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "IsUpdateNeeded": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "LevelingDelay": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "LevelingDelayMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "LevelingDelayTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Modified": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Notes": {},
                            "OvertimeCost": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "RemainingCost": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "RemainingOvertimeCost": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "Resume": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ScheduleCostVariance": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "Start": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "StartVariance": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "StartVarianceMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "StartVarianceTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Stop": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "WorkContourType": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "WorkVariance": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "WorkVarianceMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "WorkVarianceTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ActualCost": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "ActualFinish": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ActualOvertimeWork": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ActualOvertimeWorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "ActualOvertimeWorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ActualStart": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ActualWork": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ActualWorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "ActualWorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "BudgetedCost": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "BudgetedWork": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "BudgetedWorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "BudgetedWorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Cost": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "CostRateTable": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "DefaultBookingType": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "Delay": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "DelayMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "DelayTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "IsLockedByManager": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "IsWorkResource": {
                                "type": "boolean"
                            },
                            "OvertimeWork": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "OvertimeWorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "OvertimeWorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "PercentWorkComplete": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "RegularWork": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "RegularWorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "RegularWorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "RemainingOvertimeWork": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "RemainingOvertimeWorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "RemainingOvertimeWorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "RemainingWork": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "RemainingWorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "RemainingWorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ResourceCapacity": {
                                "type": [
                                    "integer",
                                    "number"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Work": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "WorkMilliseconds": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "WorkTimeSpan": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "__metadata",
                            "CustomFields",
                            "Owner",
                            "Parent",
                            "Resource",
                            "Task",
                            "ActualCostWorkPerformed",
                            "ActualOvertimeCost",
                            "BaselineCost",
                            "BaselineCostPerUse",
                            "BaselineFinish",
                            "BaselineStart",
                            "BaselineWork",
                            "BaselineWorkMilliseconds",
                            "BaselineWorkTimeSpan",
                            "BudgetedCostWorkPerformed",
                            "BudgetedCostWorkScheduled",
                            "CostVariance",
                            "CostVarianceAtCompletion",
                            "Created",
                            "CurrentCostVariance",
                            "Finish",
                            "FinishVariance",
                            "FinishVarianceMilliseconds",
                            "FinishVarianceTimeSpan",
                            "Id",
                            "IsConfirmed",
                            "IsOverAllocated",
                            "IsPublished",
                            "IsResponsePending",
                            "IsUpdateNeeded",
                            "LevelingDelay",
                            "LevelingDelayMilliseconds",
                            "LevelingDelayTimeSpan",
                            "Modified",
                            "Notes",
                            "OvertimeCost",
                            "RemainingCost",
                            "RemainingOvertimeCost",
                            "Resume",
                            "ScheduleCostVariance",
                            "Start",
                            "StartVariance",
                            "StartVarianceMilliseconds",
                            "StartVarianceTimeSpan",
                            "Stop",
                            "WorkContourType",
                            "WorkVariance",
                            "WorkVarianceMilliseconds",
                            "WorkVarianceTimeSpan",
                            "ActualCost",
                            "ActualFinish",
                            "ActualOvertimeWork",
                            "ActualOvertimeWorkMilliseconds",
                            "ActualOvertimeWorkTimeSpan",
                            "ActualStart",
                            "ActualWork",
                            "ActualWorkMilliseconds",
                            "ActualWorkTimeSpan",
                            "BudgetedCost",
                            "BudgetedWork",
                            "BudgetedWorkMilliseconds",
                            "BudgetedWorkTimeSpan",
                            "Cost",
                            "CostRateTable",
                            "DefaultBookingType",
                            "Delay",
                            "DelayMilliseconds",
                            "DelayTimeSpan",
                            "IsLockedByManager",
                            "IsWorkResource",
                            "OvertimeWork",
                            "OvertimeWorkMilliseconds",
                            "OvertimeWorkTimeSpan",
                            "PercentWorkComplete",
                            "RegularWork",
                            "RegularWorkMilliseconds",
                            "RegularWorkTimeSpan",
                            "RemainingOvertimeWork",
                            "RemainingOvertimeWorkMilliseconds",
                            "RemainingOvertimeWorkTimeSpan",
                            "RemainingWork",
                            "RemainingWorkMilliseconds",
                            "RemainingWorkTimeSpan",
                            "ResourceCapacity",
                            "Work",
                            "WorkMilliseconds",
                            "WorkTimeSpan"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you Compose the Results of the Parsed JSON

```
@{body('Parse_JSON')?['d']?['results']}
```

[image]

Now set AssignmentId to...

```
@{outputs('Compose_2')?[0]?['Id']}
```

[image]

Now create the condition.. IF AssignmentId is NOT EQUAL to Blank then...

[image]

SetAssignedTo Value is

```
@{outputs('Compose')?['d']?['Name']}
```

I am sure their is a cleaner way of doing this but at least I can extract the Resource Name (aka AssignedTo)